# Scrolling pages with multiple scroll bars in mobile Safari

Tags: ios, scroll, mobile-safari

I've a page, where in I've multiple scroll bars inside  s. When I access it from mobile safari, I'm not able to scroll through the `<div>` s. Is it the default behavior? I know that it is possible to fix it (using *Dojo/jQuery*). But I just wanted to ensure that this is how it works by default.

Regards,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is how it works by default. You'll need to use `ontouchstart` `ontouchend` and `ontouchmove` to simulate scrolling a container when accessing it on an iPhone.

Here's an article on it: http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/

Comment: So if I keep the scroll bars in the default state (no explicit code written), it is going to be very difficult to scroll through that in mobile Safari. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you won't be able to scroll through it at all. I run into this on websites and it makes me mad ... especially when it was my bank!

Comment: I guess we can use two fingers to scroll through the list. When I tried it worked for me.

Comment: This is news to me, I'll have to try it out! I don't think I've ever used two fingers a the same time, other than zooming in/out!